flutter mobile_scanner for web: could not capture barcode/qrcode
https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner
Following the example of the flutter mobile_scanner plugin for web:
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: MobileScanner(
        controller: MobileScannerController(
          detectionSpeed: DetectionSpeed.normal,
          facing: CameraFacing.front,
          torchEnabled: true,
        ),
        // fit: BoxFit.contain,
        onDetect: (capture) {
          final List<Barcode> barcodes = capture.barcodes;
          final Uint8List? image = capture.image;
          for (final barcode in barcodes) {
            debugPrint('Barcode found! ${barcode.rawValue}');
          }

          if (image != null) {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => Image(image: MemoryImage(image)),
            );
            Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            });
          }
        },
      ), 
    );
  }
}

The camera is open. But putting barcode and QR code in front of the camera (desktop, windows) and focus, the app could not capture barcode/qrcode. Nothing happened.

Have you added  inside your index.html file?

yes.  camera permission is allowed when the app is started in Chrome web.

Should there be a scan window to locate the barcode/qrcode?

Yes i think there should be a window or a widget to scan the barcode/qrcode
